# How to get a response to refund request to last.fm?

Tags: last.fm

December 13, 2012, last.fm [announced](http://www.last.fm/announcements/radio2013) that they would be discontinuing their radio service in several countries on January 15, 2013, and that customers could [request a subscription refund](http://www.last.fm/subscribe/refundrequest). I did so the very same day, because the radio service is 90% of the reason for buying it (the other being the event announcements). On January 16 the last.fm client could no longer play their radio, and I have still not heard a single word from them. Has anyone had more luck with this, and perhaps any tips to get through to them?

Comment: Same for me here. I just started a thread on the assistance forum : http://www.lastfm.fr/forum/85169/_/2200628

Answer (score 2):

I started a [thread on the assistance forum](http://www.lastfm.com/forum/21713/_/2200628) on 26th January.

The answer from a LastFm team member was:

> Next week, I believe.

So I guess people will get refund in February.

Answer (score 0):

After following the advice in [@RenaudDumont's thread](http://www.lastfm.com/forum/21713/_/2200628) I posted the following [support request](http://www.last.fm/help/support):

> Username: [removed]
>  Last payment: 19. Sep 2012
>  Paid for: 12 months'
>   subscription
>  [removed] Transaction ID: [removed]
>
> What is the status of my refund? I requested it on 13 December 2012
>   and I never heard anything back.

Anybody else having this problem should probably do the same. I wonder how many thousand they've effectively swindled so far...